# Как вызвать функцию внутри функции. Я хочу вызвать функцию sub в sum но почему то пишет что"sub идентификатор не найден", хотя наоборот работает

Tags: c++

```
int sum(int q[17], int q1[17], int C1, int C2)
{
    int kol = 0;

    if (C1 < 0 &&C2 > 0)
    {
        if (C1 * -1 > C2)
        {
        sub(q, q1, C1, C2);
return 0;
        }

        if (C1 - 1 < C2)
        {
        sub(q1, q, C1, C2);
return 0;
        }

    }
    if (C1 > 0 && C2 < 0)
    {
        if (C2 * -1 < C1)
        {
        sub(q, q1, C1, C2);
return 0;
        }

        if (C2 - 1 > C1)
        {
    //  sub(q1, q, C1, C2);
        //return 0;
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        int l = 0;
        if (q[i] == 1 && q1[i] == 1 && kol == 0 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 0;
            kol++;
        }
        if (q[i] == 1 && q1[i] == 1 && kol > 0 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 1;
        }

        if (q[i] == 1 && q1[i] == 0 && l == 0 && kol == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 1;
        }
        if (q[i] == 1 && q1[i] == 0 && l == 0 && kol > 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 0;

        }

        if (q[i] == 0 && q1[i] == 1 && l == 0 && kol == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 1;
        }

        if (q[i] == 0 && q1[i] == 1 && l == 0 && kol > 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 0;

        }

        if (q[i] == 0 && q1[i] == 0 && kol == 0 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 0;
        }

        if (q[i] == 0 && q1[i] == 0 && kol > 0 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sum1[i] = 1;
            kol--;
        }
    }
    if (C1 < 0 && C2 < 0)
    {
        sum1[16] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sum1[16] = 0;


    }
    for (int i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << sum1[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int sub1[17];
 int sub(int z[17], int z1[17], int F1, int F2)
{
    if (F1 < 0 && F2 < 0)
    {
        sum(z, z1, F1, F2);
        return 0;
    }
    if (F1 > 0 && F2 < 0)
    {
        sum(z, z1, F1, F2);
        return 0;
    }
    if (F1 < 0&&F2>0)
    {
        sum(z, z1, F1, F2);
return 0;
    }
    cout << endl;
    int o = 0;
    int o1;
    if (F2 > F1)
    {
        sub(z1, z, F1, F2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        int l = 0;
        o1 = 1;
        if (z[i] == 0 && z1[i] == 1 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            o = i + 1;
            sub1[i] = 1;
            while (o1 != 0)
            {
                if (z[o] == 0)
                {
                    z[o] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    z[o] = 0;
                    o1 = 0;

                }
                o++;
            }
        }
        if (z[i] == 0 && z1[i] == 0 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sub1[i] = 0;
        }
        if (z[i] == 1 && z1[i] == 0 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sub1[i] = 1;
        }
        if (z[i] == 1 && z1[i] == 1 && l == 0)
        {
            l = 1;
            sub1[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    if (F1 < F2)
    {
        sub1[16] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sub1[16] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << sub1[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Функции нужно *объявлять* перед вызовом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sub(int z[17], int z1[17], int F1, int F2);

int sum(int q[17], int q1[17], int C1, int C2)
{
  ...
```